# Mysql search in 2 tables left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tags

I have 2 tables.
One like this:

uin | name

The other one like this:

tag_uin | uin_item | tagname

I want to find all the uin with the tags i want, like this:

```
"SELECT nir_parts.name, nir_ntag.* FROM `nir_parts`
LEFT JOIN `nir_ntag` ON nir_parts.uin = nir_ntag.uin_item 
WHERE nir_ntag.uin = 212 AND WHERE nir_ntag.uin = 313 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 11"
```

This doesn't work for some reason...
Help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `OR` to search for 2 tags or use `IN()`

```
SELECT nir_parts.name, nir_ntag.* 
FROM nir_parts 
LEFT JOIN nir_ntag ON nir_parts.uin = nir_ntag.uin_item 
WHERE nir_ntag.uin in (212, 313)
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 11
```

A single record can't have both tags at the same time.

If you need only records where **both** tags are included you can do

```
SELECT nir_ntag.uin_item 
FROM nir_parts 
LEFT JOIN nir_ntag ON nir_parts.uin = nir_ntag.uin_item 
WHERE nir_ntag.uin in (212, 313)
group by nir_ntag.uin_item
having count(distinct nir_ntag.uin) = 2
```

Comment: But in the table "tags" its like this:
uin_item(123), tag_uin(5)
uin_item(123), tag_uin(6)

so a uin_item can have 2 tags.

Comment: Yes, but not in the same **row**. You have to group the data around your `uin_item` if you need only records where both tags are there.

Comment: any help on doing that? a tutorial would be great too.